# WpfToolkit DataGrid does not work in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wpftoolkit, windows-phone-7

I am trying to use WpfToolkit `DataGrid` in Windows Phone 7 project (Silverligt 4) and it's not working. Here is the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightControls.Grid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:wtk="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF1F1F1F" Width="960">
        <Grid x:Name="TitleGrid">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextPageTitle2Style}"/>
        </Grid>
        <wtk:DataGrid>
        </wtk:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The project compiles fine but crashes at runtime trying to load this control. The best clue I got so far is from Visual Studio Designer. Once I add `wtk:DataGrid` to the control the visual designer does not load and below is the exception it displays.

Could it be that WpfToolkit relies on PresentationFramework.dll and it's not available in SL4?

```
System.Reflection.Adds.UnresolvedAssemblyException
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: PresentationFramework, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
   at System.Reflection.Adds.AssemblyProxy.GetResolvedAssembly()
   at System.Reflection.Adds.AssemblyProxy.get_FullName()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ReflectionMetadataContext.PrepareAttributes(Reflectable`1 reflectableAssembly)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ReflectionMetadataContext.PrepareAttributes(Reflectable`1 reflectableType)
   at MS.Internal.Metadata.ClrType.GetAttributes[T](ReflectionMetadataContext context, IReflectable`1 member, ITypeMetadata attributeType, Boolean merge, AttributeMergeCache& cache)
   at MS.Internal.Metadata.ClrMember`1.GetLocalAttributes(ITypeMetadata attributeType)
   at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlType.GetSpecialProperty(Int32 idx, PropertyIdentifier pid)
   at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlType.get_ContentProperty()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlExtensionImplementations.GetContentProperty(ITypeMetadata sourceType)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlExtensions.GetContentProperty(ITypeMetadata source)
   at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionTypeNode.get_ContentProperty()
   at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.CalcChildWhitespaceImportant(XamlElement element)
   at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.ConvertChildrenToXaml(XamlElement result, PrefixScope scope, IParseContext context, IMarkupSourceProvider provider, Boolean childrenAsString)
   at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.ConvertToXaml(XamlElement parent, PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context, IMarkupSourceProvider provider)
   at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.ConvertChildrenToXaml(XamlElement result, PrefixScope scope, IParseContext context, IMarkupSourceProvider provider, Boolean childrenAsString)
   at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.ConvertToXaml(XamlElement parent, PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context, IMarkupSourceProvider provider)
   at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.ParseElementFromSkeleton(XamlParseContext context, SkeletonNode node, XamlElement parent, Boolean fullElement)
   at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.UpdateSkeleton(IDamageListener listener)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.Trees.MarkupDocumentTreeManager.Update()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.MarkupProducer.Update()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.MarkupProducer.HandleMessage(DocumentTreeCoordinator sender, MessageKey key, MessageArguments args)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.MarkupProducer.Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.IDocumentTreeConsumer.HandleMessage(DocumentTreeCoordinator sender, MessageKey key, MessageArguments args)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTreeCoordinator.SendMessage[T](MessageKey`1 key, T args, Boolean isPrivateMessage)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTreeCoordinator.QueuedMessage`1.Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.IQueuedMessage.Invoke()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTreeCoordinator.ProcessQueuedMessages(Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just when I was about to post the question, the StackOverflow tags auto-suggest showed that there is [Silverlight Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight). Clearly this is what I should use.

Since I put all that effort into the question I will leave the question and the answer as a testemant to StackOverflow awesomeness in auto-answering my question.

**EDIT** You need Silverlight 3 Toolkit binaries to use DataGrid. You need to add these four references to the project:

1. System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
2. System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll
3. System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input.dll
4. System.Windows.Data.dll